# jQuery error hander throw is not catched

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

So I have the following ajax query which fails. ajaxError is called and it throws an exception. But unfortunately the exception is not catched. Any ideas how to catch it?

```
try {
  function ajaxError(request, type, message) {
    throw 'ajaxerror ' + type + ' ' + message;
  }

  jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'http://nonexisting-example.com',
      error: ajaxError,
  });
}
catch (error) {
  alert('This: ' + error);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of ajax is asynchronous and when your ajaxError func actually gets called catch block has been already passed. If you want to catch your errors trowed during ajax call you can do something like this:

```
function ajaxError(request, type, message) {
    try {
      throw 'ajaxerror ' + type + ' ' + message;
    } catch (error) {
      alert('This: ' + error);
    }

  }
  jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'http://nonexisting-example.com',
      error: ajaxError,
  });
```

Or you can apply a pub/sub pattern to catch your async errors

Comment: What I need is a way to traverse errors out from the ajax callback. But then callbacks such as .done(function () {callback(data, error);}) will be justified. I just hoped that there would be a nicer solution and during the search forgot that the original solution might be beautiful in a way. But thank you for a well written answer.